# PHP Include_once will include file a second time if a parent directory has a different case

Tags: php, filepath, php-5.4, php-7.4, include-once

I have a directory structure as follows:

- test

  - scripts

    - testClasses.php
  - testSubDirectory

    - otherSubDirectory

      - include1.php
      - include2.php
      - includeTest.php

Here is the code for each file:
testClasses.php:

```
<?php
echo __FILE__."<br/>";
```

include1.php:

```
<?php
include_once("include2.php");
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/scripts/testClasses.php";
```

incude2.php:

```
<?php
include_once("/test/scripts/testClasses.php");
```

includeTest.php:

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/TEST/scripts/testClasses.php");
include_once("include1.php");
var_dump(get_included_files());
var_dump(get_include_path());
var_dump(__FILE__);
echo "PHP Version: ".phpversion().PHP_EOL;
```

When running PHP 5.4.3 I see the following output:
[PHP 5.4.3 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7x1A.png)

When running PHP 7.4.8 I see the following output:
[PHP 7.4.8 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg4l3.png)

Both servers are running on Windows machines.

The testClass.php file is included twice on the PHP 7.4.8 version due to the include having a different case on both even though it is the same file in the same directory.  If testClass.php had some class declarations, an error would be thrown.  Is there a way to get around this so I don't have to change the case in my include statements throughout the code?

Comment: One thing to highlight is that if you move to a hosting service which uses linux, linux IS case sensitive for file/directory names.  As a normal thing I would always ensure that your file naming is consistent and correct to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Your `testClass.php` can test if a constant is defined. If it is not defined, define it and continue with the rest of that file:

```php
if (!defined('foo')) {
  define('foo', 'bar'); // Any value will do
  // The rest of testClass.php goes here
}
```

If you want to do this for multiple `include`d files, you'll have to come up with a better naming convention than "foo", to ensure your symbols don't clash.

Alternately, if you know that `testClass.php` already defines a certain function (let's say `function foo()`), you can test for that instead:

```php
if (!function_exists('foo')) {
  // The rest of testClass.php goes here
}
```